# QGIS Server URL format for retrieving feature from a project file

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server

I'm trying to query WFS service of Qgis Server by a URL.

So far, I was succeeded to send this request:

```
http://10.253.69.120/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&MAP=/home/user/Documents/MyFirst.qgz
```

And get back this result:

```
<schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://www.qgis.org/gml" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<element name="GeoCoding_Plugin_Results" type="qgs:GeoCoding_Plugin_ResultsType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="GeoCoding_Plugin_ResultsType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="1" name="geometry" type="gml:PointPropertyType" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="fid" type="long"/>
<element nillable="true" name="address" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="JerusalemGIS_GPL0" type="qgs:JerusalemGIS_GPL0Type" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="JerusalemGIS_GPL0Type">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="1" name="geometry" type="gml:MultiPolygonPropertyType" minOccurs="0"/>
<element nillable="true" name="CODE" type="long"/>
<element nillable="true" name="SCHN_NAME" type="string"/>
<element nillable="true" name="Shape_STAr" type="decimal"/>
<element nillable="true" name="Shape_STLe" type="decimal"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="Joined_layer" type="qgs:Joined_layerType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="Joined_layerType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="1" name="geometry" type="gml:PointPropertyType" minOccurs="0"/>
<element name="fid" type="long"/>
<element nillable="true" name="address" type="string"/>
<element nillable="true" name="CODE" type="long"/>
<element nillable="true" name="SCHN_NAME" type="string"/>
<element nillable="true" name="Shape_STAr" type="decimal"/>
<element nillable="true" name="Shape_STLe" type="decimal"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<element name="אזורים_סטטיסטיים_2011_50501_Lamas_Census_Tracts_2011" type="qgs:אזורים_סטטיסטיים_2011_50501_Lamas_Census_Tracts_2011Type" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="אזורים_סטטיסטיים_2011_50501_Lamas_Census_Tracts_2011Type">
<complexContent>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

What I'm trying to is for a way to query this project and get back a feature for a specific coordinate (Which I assume I'll have to use BBOX for), but as a starting point - I'd like to get back ANY data (feature) from that map.

Trying to send this request:

```
http://10.253.69.120/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&&REQUEST=GetFeature&MAP=/home/user/Documents/MyFirst.qgz&FEATUREID=geometry.STAT11
```

Returned this error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0">
<ServiceException code="RequestNotWellFormed">TypeName 'geometry' unknown</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

I feel the solution for this is very close to me, but what should be the last step?

Comment: you don't have a TypeName called  `geometry`,  your typenames are `GeoCoding_Plugin_Results`, `JerusalemGIS_GPL0`, `Joined_layer`, and `50501_Lamas_Census_Tracts_2011`

Comment: What is the form of the gml:id when you do a GetFeature request like: `http://10.253.69.120/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&MAP=/home/user/Documents/MyFirst.qgz&version=1.1.0&typename=JerusalemGIS_GPL0&count=1`

Comment: @nmtoken Thanks for looking into this. I'll go back to the project file and check for the available typenames. As about your second comment - I'm not sure I follow. What should I look for?

Comment: in the GetFeature response you will see a `gml:id` for each feature returned